# Cancel Windows Phone SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: windows-phone-8, text-to-speech

My app is calling `SpeechSynthesizer.SpeakTextAsync` multiple time, so most of the text will be add to the queue before spoken. I want to give user the ability to cancel the speech and discard eveyything that's still in the queue.

I tried calling either `SpeechSynthesizer.CancelAll` or `SpeechSynthesizer.Dispose` and the app will just crash when either of the methods were called.

I've looked at [Cancel speech synthesis in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680027/cancel-speech-synthesis-in-windows-phone-8) but since my app add multiple speech to the queue, `Task.Cancel` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Will, it worked! Gotta read the documents more closely next time. Could you write an answer so I can mark that as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Done.  If you edit and add a small snippet of code to my answer which demonstrates, I wouldn't cry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, [according to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.cancelall%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), when you call `CancellAll`, you're cancelling the `Task`s that are executing asynchronously.  By contract, this results in an [OperationCancelledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx) being thrown.  That means that wherever you call SpeakTextAsync, SpeakSsmlAsync or SpeakSsmlFromUriAsync, you must surround these calls with a try/catch statement to prevent this exception from going uncaught.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static SpeechSynthesizer synth;

public async static Task<SpeechSynthesizer> SpeechSynth(string dataToSpeak)
        {
            synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            IEnumerable<VoiceInformation> englishVoices = from voice in InstalledVoices.All
                                                          where voice.Language == "en-US"
                                                          && voice.Gender.Equals(VoiceGender.Female)
                                                          select voice;
            if (englishVoices.Count() > 0)
            {
                synth.SetVoice(englishVoices.ElementAt(0));
            }

            await synth.SpeakTextAsync(dataToSpeak); 

            return synth;
        }  


public static void CancelSpeech()
        {
            synth.CancelAll();
        }
```

Now call the `SpeechSynth("Some Data to Speak")` where you want, and whenever you want to cancel it, just call `CancelSpeech()`.

Its Done! Enjoy...!