# How to cancel speech synthesizer on WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-synthesis

I have the `SpeechSynthesizer` reading an article in my app but when navigating from the page i call `CancelAll()` method to stop the reading but that causes my app to crash due to a `TaskCanceledException` - I tried to handle it but my program doesn't catch it and it crashes. What is the proper way to cancel it?

Comment: Share the code what you have tried, and we points you where in the code, the app breaks.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680027/cancel-speech-synthesis-in-windows-phone-8